# C# advanced constrains on generic types

Tags: c#, generics

im looking for a nice way to a synthactic problem. I want to realize a navigation system that allows to switch between different Views. The next view should be specified by its type TView (not an instance of that type). The view then will be initialized with some generic arguments

```
public abstract class ViewBase { }

public abstract class ViewBase<T0, T1> : ViewBase 
{
    public abstract void Initialize(T0 arg0, T1 arg1);
}

public static class Navigator
{
    public static void Navigate<TView, T0, T1>(T0 arg0, T1 arg1) where TView : ViewBase<T0, T1>
    {
        var view = (ViewBase<T0, T1>)Activator.CreateInstance<TView>();
        view.Initialize(arg0, arg1);

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

The code above should work, but I don't like the long list of generic types each time I call Navigate:

```
Navigate<DerivedView, string, int>("Joe", 42);
```

Assuming a derived class:

```
public class DerivedView : ViewBase<string, int> 
{
    /* ... */
}
```

In genereal it could be possible to reduce the to:

```
Navigate<DerivedView>("Joe", 42);
```

because the type information is redundant.

Do you have any suggestions?
I'm missing variadic templates ;)

Thanks

Comment: The generic parameters to `Initialize` are shadowing the class-level parameters of `ViewBase<T0, T1>` so you probably want to remove them. Then you can change `Navigate` to `Navigate<TView, T0, T1>(..) where TView : ViewBase<T0, T1>, new()`.

Comment: You are right, this was a mistake while writing the post. I don't have generic arguments there in my code. Anyhow.. This is not the real issue, it's just there to give some context..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type inference is all or nothing. If any type arguments are specified, they must all be specified. Therefore, you need a way to either:

- allow `TView` to be inferred from an argument
- avoid having `TView` as a type argument
- avoid having `T0` and `T1` as type arguments
- find a way to split the type arguments

---

You can allow `TView` to be inferred by passing in a factory function to specify `TView`'s type:

```
public static void Navigate<TView, T0, T1>(Func<TView> factory, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
        where TView : ViewBase<T0, T1> {
    var view = factory();
    view.Initialize(arg0, arg1);
    // ...
}
```

Now, instead of `Navigate<DerivedView>("Joe", 42)`, call `Navigate(() => new DerivedView(), "Joe", 42)`.

Note: this requires the types of `arg0` and `arg1` to match exactly to what `TView` specifies. Implicit conversions will not work. If the view derives from `ViewBase<int, object>`, and `arg1` is `"Hello"`, then `T1` will be inferred as type `string`, causing a compiler error message.

---

Since you avoid using `TView`'s type other than to construct the instance, you can avoid having `TView` as a type argument by using a factory function too:

```
public static void Navigate<T0, T1>(Func<ViewBase<T0, T1>> factory, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) {
    var view = factory();
    view.Initialize(arg0, arg1);
    // ...
}
```

This also avoids the problem with implicit conversions, since both `T0` and `T1` can be deduced from `factory`.

---

As for avoiding `T0` and `T1` as type arguments: the name `Initialize` somewhat suggests that its functionality may belong in a constructor. If that's the case for you, you can trivially avoid them as type arguments by leaving the construction to the caller: the factory function could be `() => new DerivedView("Joe", 42)`. However, if that's not the case for you, if you really need a separate `Initialize` method that gets called by `Navigate`, then I don't see any options that avoid `T0` and `T1` as type arguments.

---

Finally, splitting the type arguments:

```
public static class Navigator {
    public static WithViewHelper<TView> WithView<TView>()
            where TView : new() => new WithViewHelper<TView>();
    public struct WithViewHelper<TView> where TView : new() { }
}
public static class NavigatorExtensions {
    public static void Navigate<TView, T0, T1>(this Navigator.WithViewHelper<TView> withViewHelper, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
            where TView : ViewBase<T0, T1>, new() {
        var view = new TView();
        view.Initialize(arg0, arg1);
    }
}
```

This allows you to call `Navigator.WithView<DerivedView>().Navigate("Joe", 42)`. It needs `Navigate` to be an extension method because otherwise the generic type constraint cannot be expressed. It has problems again with implicit conversions: `Navigator.WithView<DerivedView>().Navigate(null, 42)` will fail to compile: even though `null` is convertible to `string`, the compiler will not figure out that `T0` should be `string`.

Comment: Thanks for your extended post. I think I'll go for the last option. I changed the naming to: 

    Navigator.To<DerivedView>().With("Joe", 42)

and called the TView constructor right in the T<TView>() Method. This makes the second call 'With(...)' optional. Till AZ's solution will be possible I think this is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is a constraint that boils down to:

`class Generic<T> where T : Generic2<T1, T2>` and have access to T1, T2 in your Generic member signatures.

Unfortunately this is not currently supported in C#.

Comment: Yes,  that was the first thing I had in mind, too :(

Answer (score 0):

Besides the presented approaches I came up with creating the object from the ViewBase class:

```
public abstract class ViewBase<T0, T1>
{
    public abstract void Initialize(T0 arg0, T1 arg1);

    public static T Navigate<T>(T0 arg0, T1 arg1) where T : ViewBase<T0, T1>
    {
        var view = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        view.Initialize(arg0, arg1);
        return view;
    }
}
```

this allows the following call:

```
DerivedView.Navigate<DerivedView>("Joe", 42);
```

but this also comes with redundant code.. or:

```
ViewBase.Navigate<DerivedView>("Joe", 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider also using a generic factory. I cache the constructor call signatures for faster retrieval the second time.

```
public static class Factory
{
    //store constructors for type T
    static Dictionary<string, ConstructorInfo> ctors=new Dictionary<string, ConstructorInfo>();

    public static T New<T>(params object[] args)
    {
        var arg_types=args.Select((obj) => obj.GetType());
        var arg_types_names=args.Select((obj) => obj.GetType().Name);

        string key=string.Format("{0}({1})", typeof(T).Name, string.Join(",", arg_types_names);

        if(!ctors.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            // if constructor not found yet, assign it
            var ctor=typeof(T).GetConstructor(arg_types.ToArray());
            if(ctor==null)
            {
                throw new MissingMethodException("Could not find appropriate constructor");
            }
            ctors[key]=ctor;
        }
        // invoke constructor to create a new T
        return (T)ctors[key].Invoke(args);
    }                
}
```